# Logback issue when importing jar

Tags: java, spring, jar, static-libraries, logback

I imported a third-party library into my Java/Spring project (just importing, nothing from the library is used) and when I run the app I get:

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1aea858e - Missing integer token, that is %i, in FileNamePattern [jboss.server.log.dir_IS_UNDEFINED/bak-library-%d{yyyy-MM}.log.zip]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1aea858e - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#sat_missing_integer_token
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
```

I was wondering - is this an issue with the third-party library itself or I can add some configuration in my project in order to fix this (basically the library assumes that a client will provide such configuration so it throws an error if there isn't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the link in the exception you find

> **Missing integer token, that is %i, in FileNamePattern [...].**
>
> The %i conversion token is mandatory for [size and time based archiving](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy). In case the %i token is missing, SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP attached to RollingFileAppender will detect the omission and will not start.

As you use a `RollingFileAppender` you follow the above link [size and time based archiving](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy)

Changing your pattern for example as following should solve the problem.

```
jboss.server.log.dir_IS_UNDEFINED/bak-library-%d{yyyy-MM}.%i.log.zip
```

Comment: Thanks! But where do I change this? The error comes from a third-party library and I don't have its source code. If I put logback configuration in my project will it affect the logging of the library?

Comment: @asenovm I would expect that your library mention in its documentation where you need to store the logback configuration. Where is this file pattern `bak-library-%d{yyyy-MM}.log.zip` defined?

Answer (score 0):

From the exception, I think the problem is, it is not able to parse this

```
jboss.server.log.dir_IS_UNDEFINED
```

It is not able to load this property that leads to an exception.